# CSS - What is causing the Whitespace

Tags: html, css

When I insert an image into the `<aside>` element, it now "pushes" the `<section>` element roughly 50% down on the screen, this leaves 50% of whitespace on the screen, I have absolutely no idea what is causing it, the Dev console doesn't pick any errors up, Yet on all my browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Edge, all display it with this whitespace.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Whitespace].

And here is a snippet:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
    display: inline-block;
}
html {  
    height: 100vh;
}
body { 
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Main Content Page */

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;     
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18vh;
    background-color: orange;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: orange; 
}
.hello {
    width: 70%;
    height: 40vh;
}
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: darkgrey; 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset; 
}
```

```html
<body>

   <main id="content">

      <header>
        <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
      </header>

      <aside>
        <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
        <img src="Images/Businessman/Hello.png" alt="Welcome" class="hello" />
      </aside><!--
        This comment is to help remove the whitespace between these elements :/
      --><section>
        <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
        <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
        <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
        <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
      </section><!--
        This comment is to help remove the whitespace between these elements :/
   --></main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is more of a positioning issue than a whitespace issue. I think there's an `align` property that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align: top;`to your `section` tag.

**Explaination :**
The `display` property of your blocks is set to `inline-block`, so they will use the `vertical-align` property, which is by default to `baseline`.
In your case you want them to align at the top, so you have to specify it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
    display: inline-block;
}
html {  
    height: 100vh;
}
body { 
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Main Content Page */

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;     
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18vh;
    background-color: orange;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: orange; 
}
.hello {
    width: 70%;
    height: 40vh;
}
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: darkgrey; 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <main id="content">

  <header>
   <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
  </header>

  <aside>
   <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   <img src="Images/Businessman/Hello.png" alt="Welcome" class="hello" />
  </aside><!--
   This comment is to help remove the whitespace between these elements :/
  --><section>
   <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
  </section><!--
   This comment is to help remove the whitespace between these elements :/
 --></main>

 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain how that works, I have never had to use that before?

Comment: As your blocks are `display: inline-block`, they use the property of `vertical-align`. By default, `vertical-align: baseline`. So if you want those blocks to be vertically aligned at the top, you have to specify it.

Comment: Makes sense. If you would like to put that in your answer, Just so it may help others, I will accept it, Thanks